# Swift installation error on Ubuntu 14.04(32 bit installation) - 64bit Machine

Tags: 14.04, bash

I have followed steps specified here https://swift.org/download/#linux

When I try to run command

> swift --version

It throws error

> bash: /home/dhiraj/swift2/usr/bin/swift: cannot execute binary file:
>   Exec format error

how to resolve this?

Comment: The package you linked to appears to be for 64-bit systems only: I don't think there's any way to resolve that if you have a 32-bit system, you will need to build a 32-bit version from source (or find someone who has done that and made the result available - perhaps through a PPA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To date, Swift is only available for 64-bit systems. You are running on 32-bit, as is visible from your error.

Currently, you have three options:

- Install a 64-bit distribution;
- Buy a 64-bit PC;
- Wait for Apple to release a 32-bit version.

I'd probably opt for the 64-bit choice...

Comment: I have CPU that supports 64 bit distribution. CPU op-mode(s):  32-bit,64-bit should i upgrade to 64 bit distribution?

Comment: @kamlesh.bar Yes you should. 32bit is old, maybe buggy, and appropiate for home systems from like, 2001.

Comment: @StarOS buggy? not at all - but yes, you should install a 64 bit distribution

Comment: @DevRobot I said *maybe* buggy.